# iOS. How I can caught exception, when other code already uses NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exception

I want to use global exception handler.

Call in applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions this:

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
```

And use this for handling exception:

```
    void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
        // handling exception
}
```

But also I use sdk, which already uses NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler. Then my method uncaughtExceptionHandler hasn't called when exception is happens.

I know that can be only one handler for one app. But I need that and sdk, and this code can handle exceptions on global level.

Do you have any ideas how I can use NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler in this case? Or other ideas how I can handle exceptions on global level?
Great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Call `installUncaughtExceptionHandler()` after the SDK `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` will cover the handler. Than your `uncaughtExceptionHandler` will be called.

Further on, you can store the handler of the SDK, and call it in your `uncaughtExceptionHandler` to make the SDK work together.

Example code:

```
static NSUncaughtExceptionHandler *exceptionHandler = NULL;

typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
static sighandler_t sigHandler = NULL;

static void handleException(NSException *e)
{
    //your code ...

    //call the SDK handler
    if (exceptionHandler) {
        exceptionHandler(e);
    }
}

static void handleSignal(int signal)
{
    //your code ...

    if (sigHandler) {
        sigHandler(signal);
    }
}

void installUncaughtExceptionHandler()
{
    // store the SDK handler
    exceptionHandler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&handleException);

    sigHandler = signal(SIGABRT, handleSignal);
    signal(SIGILL, handleSignal);
    signal(SIGSEGV, handleSignal);
    signal(SIGFPE, handleSignal);
    signal(SIGBUS, handleSignal);
    signal(SIGPIPE, handleSignal);
}
```